# What's a resonable maximum size of pandas dataframe that give acceptable time for deep learning models?

Tags: python, performance, pandas, scikit-learn

I am working with a pandas dataframe of shape `(37,050,959 ;  24)` and

```
print(data.info(memory_usage='deep'))
```

gives a memory usage of 3.6 GB. Then I tried to apply a `MLPClassifier`on these data, keeping 2/3 of the data (i.e. 24,700,639) for the training, splitting them into 10 folds for cross-validation. However it seems to take a lot of time and when I was using double precision floats, it causes memory problems (using simple precision floats helped to decrease memory usage from nearly a half).

My question is : What's a resonable maximum size of dataframe that could give acceptable time results while going through a neural network of Keras or Scikit-Learn library ? Are the previous sizes too big ? If yes, is there more clever way than just dropping some data ?

I have 6GB of RAM on my laptop... I am not familiar with Python multiprocessing, could it help ?

Comment: One of the things I would do is first to try to tun the model on a gpu (if you are not doing it already). Second thing I would do since you have a lot of data I would try first to try and train a model to a significantly smaller amount of data (maybe 1 milion is enough; it is hard to tell) just to see how it goes and then you can increase the amount of data. That is what I would do :)

Comment: ok, thanks for the advice